# docker (running in virtual box) expose port on host machine

Tags: networking, docker, port, virtualbox, docker-machine

I'm running docker in **virtual box** (docker machine) on a **MAC server**. I have some running containers that expose certain ports to the host machine, so I can access them via **URL of the virtual machine + exposed port**. But I'm **not** able to reach the exposed services f**rom outside** the host system, as the docker containers are sandboxed in their own virtual network I guess.

Is it possible to also expose the port on the host machine so people from outside can reach the web services running in docker inside my virtual machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options:

- Selecting Bridged Networking: in bridged mode, the virtual machine will appear as a separate device on your network and have its own IP address.
- Port forwarding (NAT): This is only necessary when you don't want to use the Bridge apdater

I hope this [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/) can help you.